# How to extract part of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to extract part of an array using numpy. I look it up and it seems that there are plenty of ways to do so either (for example [np.delete()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)). However, I can't manage to make it work for my problem.

I have a big array with a `shape(80,2,100,100,3)` I want to divide this array into two sliding part using a loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(data), len(data)//2):
     part_1 = data[i:i+len(data)//5] #Initial selection
     part_2 = data[0:i::i+len(data)//5:] #Selection of the rest of the initial data

for i in range (0, len(data), len(data)//2):
    part_1 = data[i:i+len(data)//5]
    part_2 = np.delete(data, obj=part_1, axis=0)
```

Both solutions don't work. Does anyone have an idea?

Kind regards,

Unic0

Comment: numpy.split ? numpy.array_split?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get (what are the shapes of the resulting `part_1` and `part_2` that you want)? The for-loops in your code are useless because the result is obtained for the final `i` only.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that by splitting the problem in two parts:

```
for i in range(0,len(data),len(data)//5):

        part_1 = data[i:i+len(data)//5]

        temp0 = data[0:i]
        temp1 = data[i+len(data)//5:]
        part_2 = np.concatenate((train_images0, train_images1), axis=0)
```

However, I am certain there would be a better way to do that in one step.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be more than welcome.

Regards,

Unic0

Comment: In the above code the for-loop is useless because the final result is computed for the final `i=64`, so `part_1 = data[64:80]`.

Comment: This is just part of a way larger code, which will be using the part_2 array. But thank you for your comment